# Inequality involving greatest integer function

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, ceiling-and-floor-functions

How to prove that following inequality is not true for any natural number $n\ge 5$

$$2\left\lfloor \frac{n}{3}\right\rfloor-2>n-1-\sqrt{(n+1)^2-4(n-1)\left\lfloor \frac{n-1}{2}\right\rfloor+4\left\lfloor \frac{n-3}{2}\right\rfloor^2}$$

Comment: I wouldn't say it's the "greatest integer", I would all the time long speak of the floor function.

Comment: Write n=6m+k, k=[0..5] and look at the cases. This gets rid of the greatest integer funxtion.

Comment: @marty cohen, I looked at each case and it's working fine but can we think in terms of taking left side as $f$,right as $g$ and showing that $f-g$ is a decreasing function and its value at $n=5$ is negative. Here I am not able to prove that $f-g$ is decreasing. Any help?

Comment: The best I can say,  without working on it, is to use $x-1<\lfloor x \rfloor \le x$ to get lower and upper bounds for each side. But you have probably done this.

Comment: I've added a proof that RHS is larger than LHS for $n=5$ and for all $n\ge 7$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not true.

For $n=6$, LHS is larger than RHS since
$$\text{LHS}=2=5-\sqrt 9\gt 5-\sqrt{13}=\text{RHS}$$

---

We have $\text{LHS}\lt \text{RHS}$ for $n=5$ and all $n\ge 7$.

*Proof* :

Let $f(n)=\text{LHS}$, $g(n)=\text{RHS}$.

Using that $x-1\lt\lfloor x\rfloor\le x$, we have

$$\begin{align}&g(n)-f(n)\\\\&=n-1-\sqrt{(n+1)^2-4(n-1)\left\lfloor \frac{n-1}{2}\right\rfloor+4\left\lfloor \frac{n-3}{2}\right\rfloor^2}-\left(2\left\lfloor \frac{n}{3}\right\rfloor-2\right)\\\\&=n-2\left\lfloor\frac n3\right\rfloor+1-\sqrt{(n+1)^2-4(n-1)\left\lfloor \frac{n-1}{2}\right\rfloor+4\left\lfloor \frac{n-3}{2}\right\rfloor^2}
\\\\&\gt n-2\cdot\frac n3+1-\sqrt{(n+1)^2-4(n-1)\left(\frac{n-1}{2}-1\right)+4\left(\frac{n-3}{2}\right)^2}
\\\\&=\frac 13(n+3-6\sqrt{n+1})\end{align}$$
which is positive for all $n\ge 31$.

We can see that $g(n)\gt f(n)$ for $n=5$ or $7\le n\le 30$.